# node.js ENOTFOUND on windows despite working on mac

Tags: node.js, vue.js, mamp

After having deployed a small project on mac I tried to get it running on another PC, windows this time (only have access to that one atm).

Using the same code, node.js version etc. I run into a problem.

When making a call to my mamp apache from my vue project (vue has host 8080, the apache server 80) I get greeted with a error 500 ENOTFOUND.

I configured the proxy in my vue.config which works on mac just fine. Strange thing on windows is I can change the localhost port (or 127.0.0.1) to whatever I want, it will always get resolved to port 80.

Anything I am overlooking here?

Comment: ENOTFOUND is typically a DNS issue. Are you using names or ipaddresses? Maybe you have some hostname defined in `/etc/hosts` on your mac which is not defined in the `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file on windows?

Comment: And ports don't get "resolved" only ip addresses are resolved. Ports you have to explicitely specify in your url. Otherwise the default port is 80 for http and 443 for https.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Only had time to check back. After reading up more and comparing hosts etc I went back and just re-added axios. Turns out that this fixed it.